# Using NSFontPanel in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfontpanel

I'm trying to use an NSFontPanel to allow the user to change an application-wide font setting. It's supposed to work something like this: the user clicks a button, a font panel pops up, they choose a font and a size, and their selection is persisted.

The following code shows the panel:

```
- (IBAction)showFontMenu:(id)sender {
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontManager setDelegate:self];

    NSFontPanel *fontPanel = [fontManager fontPanel:YES];
    [fontPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
```

The documentation seems to suggest that the changeFont:(id)sender method should be called when the font changes; this isn't happening in my case.

```
- (void)changeFont:(id)sender {
    // blah
}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This issue helped me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147305/why-isnt-changefont-being-called-from-my-nsfontpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you've defined `-changeFont:` on must the first responder or above it in the responder chain. You haven't specified where you've defined the method, but I assume it's on a controller object that is not in the responder chain.

Comment: The View Controller's view is actually being loaded into another window; adding changeFont: to the parent's ViewController worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

include this:

```
[fontManager setTarget:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSFontManager`'s delegate exists primarily to filter the fonts it supplies to the font panel via `-fontManager:willIncludeFont:`.

As kperryua mentions, `-changeFont:` is sent up the responder chain. The button that launches the font menu or its enclosing view might be a good place to put a responder for `-changeFont:`.

You might find the [Font Handling](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontHandling/FontHandling.html) guide marginally more useful than the [Font Panel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontPanel/FontPanel.html) guide.

Comment: Correct link: [Apple's Font Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html)

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is this line:

```
[fontPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

By making the font panel the key window, it's got no idea where to send action messages like -changeFont: to.

Comment: I changed it to orderFrontFontPanel:; but the problem was actually with the responder chain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working implementation. Key point is you should make your object as the first responder where you have implemented `- (void)changeFont:(id)sender`

```
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];

NSFontPanel *panel = [fontManager fontPanel:YES];
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];

[panel orderFront:self];
```

Simple changeFont: implementation Reference - [Font Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/FontHandling/FontHandling.html)

```
-(void) changeFont:(id)sender
{
    //Here sender would be NSFontManager
    NSFont *oldFont = [self font];
    NSFont *newFont = [sender convertFont:oldFont];
    [self setFont:newFont];
}
```