# Filtering Font Panel from NSToolbar

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem, nsfont, nsfontpanel

I've got `NSToolbar` with Fonts item. Is it possible to set filter for fonts in Fonts table? For example I don't want *Arial* in font family table.

Or second way - Is it possible to make own group in Fonts as Collection? Thx 4 reply.

Comment: It helps using the proper Cocoa terminology so people understand what you're trying to do - are you talking about the [Font Panel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontPanel/Concepts/TextFontPanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000835-CJBBIAAF)??

Comment: Yes, It's about Font Panel. Thx for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the fonts displayed in the [Font Panel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontPanel/FontPanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000116i) by using a [Font Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFontManager) delegate and implementing[`fontManager:willIncludeFont:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/fontManager:willIncludeFont:) to filter the fonts displayed by the Font Panel.

You might find additional infos here:
 [Using NSFontPanel in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415716/using-nsfontpanel-in-cocoa)